# Expanding around the fixed points in renormalization group

Tags: renormalization, effective-field-theory

In the textbook "The Kondo problem to heavy fermions", by Hewson (1997), chapter 4, the expansion of transformation around a fixed point $K^*$ is written as:
$$R_\alpha(K^*+\delta K)=K^*+L_\alpha^* \delta K +...,$$
where $L_\alpha^*$ is an operator acting on $\delta K$. However, from expansion of a function around a given point we know that
$$f(x+a)=f(x)+\frac{df}{dx}|_{x=a}dx +...$$ where $\frac{df}{dx}|_{x=a}$ in not an operator and doesn't act on $dx$. I would be grateful if someone please help me with the confusion in the correspondence between the two formulas.

Comment: Suppose you have a multivariate function, which can be written as the function of a vector, $f(\mathbf{x})$. The series expansion around some other vector is $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{a}) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) + \dots.$ The term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{a})$ is a matrix--a finite-dimensional operator--that acts on $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: Many thanks bbrink. Your matrix view helped me very much.